# Django Admin Interface design is different

Tags: django, django-admin

The django version is 1.9.2.

I have my website on two different servers ( the same website) the problem is that the  Django admin interface on the first server is different from that on the second here are some screenshots of the two copies of the admin website

[image: first django admin login]
[image: second django admin login]

Comment: They're probably different django versions

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic` after upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading to a new Django version it is smart to read the release notes. Not only the release notes of the target but all versions in between. That way you know what you are going for.

1.9 introduces new styling see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/#new-styling-for-contrib-admin

> ### New styling for contrib.admin
>
> The admin sports a modern, flat design with new SVG icons which look perfect on HiDPI screens. It still provides a fully-functional experience to YUI’s A-grade browsers. Older browser may experience varying levels of graceful degradation.

You run your website on two different machines each with another Django versions installed. By deploying to a new server with newer Django you 'unknowingly upgraded'. Inspect the version you are using with:

```
$ python manage.py version
```

Downgrade Django to get your old admin style back.

Comment: thank you very much for your help... I upgraded the copy on the second server to version 1.9.2 but still the same old admin interface. I need to have the new admin interface look not the old one so what should i do ? uninstall django then install the version 1.9.2 ?? thank you again for your help

Comment: Yes, first `pip uninstall Django` and then `pip install Django==1.9.2`. I would advice you to use the latest 1.9.x (1.9.9) as this version has many bugfixes. See the release notes. You also have to run `collectstatic` to update your static files.

Answer (score 0):

The design of the Django admin has changed in the [1.9 release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.9/#new-styling-for-contrib-admin). If you think you have upgraded both projects to Django >= 1.9, you must check your requirements, since the first one clearly still runs with Django 1.8 or less.

Comment: thank uou all for your help collectstatic has solved the problem thanks alot